# PyGObject: Can't control a progressbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygobject

If I use **.set_text()** and **.set_fraction()** methods from module level, all successfully.

But if I do this from function or by sending object to other module, nothing happens.

I use Glade. I wrote a program for 5 minutes. Glade:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.16.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.10"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkProgressBar" id="progressbar1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="fraction">0.0</property>
        <property name="pulse_step">0.10</property>
        <property name="show_text">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window2">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
        <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">True</property>
        <property name="receives_default">True</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Very terrible Python script:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import time

def go(*args):
    progress.set_text("Progress...")
    for did in range(100):
        progress.set_fraction(did / 100)
        time.sleep(0.1)

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("test.glade")
win = builder.get_object("window1")
win2 = builder.get_object("window2")
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
progress = win.get_child()
button = win2.get_child()
button.connect("clicked", go)
win.show_all()
win2.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

**UPD1:** My steps:

1. I'm pressing button
2. The proggressbar staying in old position
3. When a loop is completed, the progressbar updates

**UPD2:** [video](https://youtu.be/LQLK0bn8KUg)

Comment: Your main problem is that you are not incrementing `did` in your loop, also that you are doing integer division, which will always evaluate to zero while `did < 100`. Change to `(did / 100.0)` to force a float. This still will not update the progbar until the end though, you need to use `idle_add`, probably for that.

Comment: @SiHa, I use Python3

Comment: Ok that will increment without being told to will it?

Comment: @SiHa, I added video...

Answer (score 1):

You're running your progression loop within the gtk main loop. Therefore you're blocking the main loop and all redrawing is delayed until the loop has completed.

You can see this using the `threading` module like the following:

```
button.connect("clicked", lambda *a: threading.Thread(target=go, args=a).start())
```

This time the progessbar updates work.

Comment: This is true except Gtk is not thread-safe. Using something like `timeout_add` can do repeated calls to update the progressbar.

Comment: Please avoid using threads, as already mentioned there are specific functions to achieve the same results.